# Using Groebner Basis to eliminte variables but end with empty set.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, groebner-basis

I want to infer the relationship between `x` and `y` (which is `x == y`) as the code (mathematica) below.
However `l2` gives an empty set `{}` when I eliminate `A, B`.

I wonder what's the theorem beind it?

It is because situation `A==B==0` ?

Is that possible to add an assumption of `A!=0 && B !=0` when computating Groebner Basis?

```
l2 = {
   x A - y B,
   A - B
   };
l3 = {
   4 x - 4 y,
   A - B
   };
GroebnerBasis[l2, {}, {A, B}]
GroebnerBasis[l3, {}, {A, B}]
```

Got answer

```
{}
{x - y}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumptions $A \neq 0$ and $B \neq 0$ can taken into account by adding variables `Ainv, Binv` for the inverses of `A` and `B`, and adding the polynomials `A*Ainv - 1, B*Binv - 1` to the list of generators. Eliminating `A, B, Ainv, Binv` will then yield `{x - y}`.